# get_post_meta inside echo

Tags: post-meta

I have a serious problem :)

I have this code:

```
<?php global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'provinciadestacada', true); ?>
```

And i want include here:

```
<?php if ( in_category( '951' )) { echo 'Online'; }
else
?>
```

After else i want get post_meta "provinciadestacada"

Maybe something like this?

```
<?php if ( in_category( '951' )) {
echo 'Online. Todas las provincias'; }
else echo "global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$meta = get_post_meta($postid, 'provinciadestacada', true);"
?>
```

Comment: What you are doing is just very, very bad PHP. You need to construct a string and echo that, not try to echo the actual PHP like that.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Can you help me with code example please? I'm new in programmation and i must learn a lot. The first code works fine, but i don't know how implement that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this

```
<?php if ( in_category( '951' )) {
echo 'Online. Todas las provincias'; }
else { 
      global $wp_query;
      $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
      $meta = get_post_meta($postid, 'provinciadestacada', true);
     echo $meta;
 }

?>
```

To do it in reverse as you want:

```
  global $wp_query;
  $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
  $meta = get_post_meta($postid, 'provinciadestacada', true);

   if(!empty($meta)) {
        echo $meta;
   }

    elseif(in_category( '951' )) {
        echo 'Todas las provincias';
     }
```